# solutions for linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Let there be: $$2\cdot a\cdot y+\left(a+4\right)\cdot x = 0$$
>
> $$\left(2\cdot a+6\right)\cdot z+\left(16\cdot a-16\right)\cdot y+ \left(6\cdot a+24\right)\cdot x = 4\cdot a-2$$
>
> $$\left(8\cdot a+16\right)\cdot z+\left(54\cdot a-56\right)\cdot y+ \left(20\cdot a+80\right)\cdot x = 14\cdot a-8$$
>
> For which $a$ there is no solution/one solution/infinite solutions

The RREF I got is: $$\
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a+4 & 2a & 0  & 0 \\
0 & 2a-8 & a+3  & 2a-1 \\
0 & 0 & a-5  & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

definitely $a=5$ ,How should I proceed from here for one solution/infinite solutions? (when I need to provide 3 $a$ for one solution and 2 $a$ for infinite solutions)

Comment: @mfl edited, I must supply specific $a$'s

Comment: Are you familiar wiht Rouché–Capelli theorem? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem)

Comment: @mfl yes, so a=4 and a=-4 are the solutions for infinite solutions?

Comment: @gbox I think the last term of the second row would be $2a-1$ instead of $a-1$

Comment: @mint fixed, thanks

Comment: If $a=4$ then $\mbox{rank}(A)=\mbox{rank}(A|B)=2.$ So, infinite solutions. If I am not wrong, if $a=-4$ it is $\mbox{rank}(A)=2$ and $\mbox{rank(A|B)}=3.$ That is, no solution.